# Access StoryBoard from a template

Tags: .net, wpf, animation, triggers, storyboard

Here is some class I got :

```
<Style x:Key="BoutonMenu" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="BtnHover" AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="-1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="BtnClick" AutoReverse="False">
                        <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                        </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="-1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="-1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="-1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#FF337641"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="BtnRevert">
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF337641"/>
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="Black"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                        </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="#FF000000" Background="#FF000000" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="20" Opacity="1" >
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                    <Grid x:Name="grid">
                        <Border x:Name="mask" Background="White" CornerRadius="20"/>
                        <!-- Background Layer -->
                        <Grid x:Name="grid1">
                            <Grid.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=mask}"/>
                            </Grid.OpacityMask>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FF000000" >
                                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="RefractionLayer">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                                <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0.819" Color="#00000000"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF020000" Offset="0.187"/>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Margin="0,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>

                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BtnHover_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BtnClick_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="BtnClick_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource BtnClick}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BtnHover_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="BtnHover_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource BtnHover}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.25"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you can see, I have 3 different storyboards, two of which happen on specific triggers. I have a third one (BtnRevert) that I would like to start on demand. I can't really seem to find how to do it. Is this possible, if yes how and if not how can I bypass that ?

Edit : So I tried this :

```
        Dim s As Storyboard = _oCurMenuBouton.Template.Resources("BtnRevert")
        s.Begin()
```

It seems to get the storyboard right, but now I get this :

```
No applicable name scope exists to resolve the name 'rectangle'.
```

It seems it does not recognize the storyboard has being the property of my button or at least the template. Is there any way to make it work ?

Got it to work ! Here is the answer

```
        Dim s As Storyboard = _oCurMenuBouton.Template.Resources("BtnRevert")
        s.Begin(_oCurMenuBouton,_oCurMenuBouton,Template)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try this

```
  <Button Height="25"
            Margin="5"
            Style="{StaticResource BoutonMenu}" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
```

in the code Behind

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rButton = sender as Button;
        if (rButton != null)
        {
            Storyboard s = (Storyboard)rButton.Template.Resources["BtnRevert"];
        }  
    }
```

Comment: I'll try it ASAP. It's weird, but I had the impression I tried that (I remember doing it without the template and it didn't work out) but I'll try again.